# How to make a simple Java LAN server for a game

Tags: java, server, p2p

I'm currently making a simple game in Java where players move around a maze that is constantly generating around them and killing monsters that spawn. However, I wanted to improve this by adding a simple co-op functionality across their LAN. I've never looked into networking at all and thought it would be a good idea to learn a bit about it by trying it out in my game.

Are there any simple useful tutorials on how to make a basic peer-to-peer server which would let people connect over LAN, specifically Java but how they work too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways you could develop a LAN multiplayer game. I suppose that the easiest one would revolve around using Sockets.

With this in mind you'll need to create a server application that will accept incoming connection from clients and would then marshal the whole operation. With that in place you'll need to create the clients that will connect to said server.

I suppose that other than plain sockets you could also implement the same functionality using Java's RMI. You can take a look at an example here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/hello/hello-world.html

A simple Google search though should yield quite a lot of results and examples regarding this matter (LAN games in Java).